# How to style a module or article title with font awesome icons?

Tags: module, custom-module, helix3

I am using the Helix framework template.

Is it possible to add a font awesome icon to a module or article title? If yes, how do I go about it?

I have seen around that you can style a title using the header class in the advanced section of the module, but I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

You could add some custom CSS like this or similar:

```
.page-class .page-header h1::before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
```

Use a page class to target a specific page.

You can find a list of icons and their codes at: https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use different icons in titles you can use the [RokCandy Macro](https://rockettheme.com/joomla/extensions/rokcandy).